# Label is not updating iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I have singleton class in which I declare an int and a `NSTimer` so both are globally accessible. I decrease int value using timer and display on label which declare at A class.

What happened is that it decreases and keeps updating int value on label but when user moves back to A class and then jump into it doesn't update value.

I have logged the int and the text value of label and both are working fine but does no update onto view.

Please help me and indicate me where I am doing wrong. If anyone does not understand I'll update question with code.

Comment: maybe  you did not set the label as an outlet? anyway you need to show some of the code

Comment: If not connected then how it updates label when I remain on A class. What exactly code you need to understand? What to show ?

Comment: At least you should show how you create the NSTimer, and how you invalidate it, also how you update the label, the timer interval etc..

Comment: I recommend including code in your question.

Comment: Are you invalidating the timer when you move to other view controllers?